# CDH 5.3.2: Load data inpath failing with "no visible files" error

Tags: hive, hdfs, impala, cloudera-cdh

We have a reporting application built using Hadoop, Hive and Impala on CDH 5.3.2 set up. All of our jobs were scheduled from a single node (called Orchestration Node). No Hadoop service was deployed on this node. However as it was a potential single point of failure for the whole application, we introduced High Availability for it by adding another passive Orchestration node and using rcron (keep-alive) to maintain active passive sync.

However due to some flaws in the implementation, there was a scenario where in both nodes came up. During this period there were some jobs which were trying to write to the same HDFS directory resulting in below exception being thrown in logs:

```
8/03/16 07:26:16 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Error Recovery for block BP-793706682-10.3.8.147-1434350563384:blk_1128320405_57247539 in pipeline 10.3.3.163:50010, 10.3.8.130:50010, 10.3.3.252:50010: bad datanode 10.3.3.163:50010
18/03/16 07:26:16 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): BP-793706682-10.3.8.147-1434350563384:blk_1128320405_57247539 does not exist or is not under Constructionnull
```

One of the Orch nodes was brought down manually but then we started seeing below error from one of our scripts which was trying to load data into a table from HDFS

```
Query: load DATA INPATH '/tmp/aaa/bbbb' INTO TABLE temp.data_aaa_bbbb_temp
ERROR: AnalysisException: INPATH location 'hdfs://xyz-nameservice/tmp/aaa/bbbb' contains no visible files.
Could not execute command: load DATA INPATH '/tmp/aaa/bbbb' INTO TABLE temp.data_aaa_bbbb_temp
```

I am not sure what caused this error. Did the HDFS directory get corrupted when two jobs were trying to write to same location at same time?

I was able to work around the issue by deleting and recreating the hdfs location however this issue seems to occur again and again.

Along with possible root cause I am also looking for suggestions on permanently fixing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here was with design of the script. 
It was doing two things: 
1) Loading data into a staging table
2) Inserting data into main table after some processing.

The script was failing at Step 2 however due to retry mechanism built in the script it was retrying the script from Step 1 not just the part where it failed.

Hence the load data step was being executed again. However this step was already executed successfully and there were no files left to be moved resulting in no visible files exception.

I have finally refactored my script into two individual components to take care of this.